# UITableView reload data in Swift

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, ios8

There's this code of the test project in Objective-C:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *_locations;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://mechnikova.info/api/pic2.php?task=1"]; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    _locations = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];

    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

There's this code of the same test project in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
var locations:NSArray=[]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var jsonLoader:JSONLoader = JSONLoader()
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://mechnikova.info/api/pic2.php?task=1")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
        self.locations = jsonLoader.locationsFromJSONFile(url)
        self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(selector:(reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    })
}
```

I have error - **Use of unresolved identifier 'reloadData'** in

```
self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(selector:(reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

Help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
        self.locations = jsonLoader.locationsFromJSONFile(url)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
```

Comment: Who say you that please look my below answer on iOS9

Comment: You're right, reading in the documentation it's not deprecated, but it's not available when I try to run this..

Answer (score 2):

for convenience, you can use Costant

```
let diffQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)
let diffMain = dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

and then used in a viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
dispatch_async(diffQueue) {
           self.locations = jsonLoader.locationsFromJSONFile(url)
                dispatch_async(self.diffMain){
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

```
self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(selector:(reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

with this

```
self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("reloadData"), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

The diff is in creating selector